# Creating a new entity with polymorphic attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm creating a tagging system across three different entity types. I'm running into trouble implementing it as an associated, polymorphic attribute. Editing an existing contact seems to work (it creates the associated record), but when creating a new contact, it simply does not create the other record. There is only one associated record as each tag is recorded into one long text field as a single string.

contact.rb:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :tag, :as => taggable
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :tag, :allow_destroy => true, 
     :reject_if => :all_blank
```

tag.rb:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :taggable, :polymorphic => true
```

contacts_controller.rb:

```
def new
   @contact = Contact.new
   @contact.tag = Tag.new
end

def edit
  @contact = Contact.find(params[:id])
  if @contact.tag.nil?
    @contact.tag = Tag.new
  end
end
```

new.html.erb:

```
<%= fields_for :tag do |tag| %>
<div class="clearfix">
  <%= tag.label :tags, 'Tags' %>
  <div class="input">
    <%= tag.text_field :tags %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What happens if you do `form.fields_for` instead of just bare `fields_for` (assuming form is the variable for the yielded form from the outer `form_for`)

Comment: That actually worked. If you move this comment to an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is that you're not telling the `fields_for` what object it's performing the `nested_attributes_for` for.

Prefix the fields for with the name of your outer `form_for` object and it should work.